# (Ray tracing) Trouble converting to screen coordinates, objects being stretched

Tags: c++, graphics, camera, aspect-ratio, raytracing

I followed along with *Ray Tracing in One Weekend* and managed to get the final output but I wanted to understand more about creating a camera and "painting" the screen since he didn't go over it much.

When I tried using a different way of creating a camera by spheres actually get elongated, making them look like more like ellipses. I've tried modifying the x and y assignments in `screenCords` but I've only managed to make more errors (such as objects wrapping around to the opposite side)

Camera.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "../Matrix.h"
#include "../Defs.h"
#include "Defs.h"

template<typename O>
using Point3 = Vec3<O>;

template<typename O>
using Color = Vec3<O>;

template <typename O>
class Camera{
  O Height;
  O Width;
  Vec3<O> Forward, Right, Up;
  Point3<O> Origin;

public:
  Camera(O fov, O aspect_ratio, Point3<O> origin, Point3<O> target, Vec3<O> upguide) {
    Height = atan(degrees_to_radians(fov));
    Width = Height * aspect_ratio;
    
    Origin = origin;

    Forward = target - origin;
    Forward.normalize();
    Right = Forward.cross(upguide);
    Right.normalize();
    Up = Right.cross(Forward);

    }

    Ray<O> get_raydir(O right, O up){
      Vec3<O> result(Forward + right * Width * Right + up * Height * Up); result.normalize();

      return Ray<O>(Origin, result);
    }

    void screenCords(O &x, O &y, O width, O height){
      x = ((2.0f * x) / width) -1.0f;
      y = ((2.0f * y) / height); 
    }
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "../Matrix.h"
#include "Camera.h"
#include <vector>
#include "Image.h"
#include "Shapes.h"
#include "Tracer.h"
#include "../Defs.h"

template<typename O>
using Point3 = Vec3<O>;

template<typename O>
using Color = Vec3<O>;

int main(){
  const int img_ratio = 2;
  const int img_width = 640;
  const int img_height = 480;
  const int depth = 50; float t_Max = infinity; float t_Min = 0.001;

  float inv_width = 1 / float(img_width);
  float inv_height = 1 / float(img_height);

  std::vector<Sphere<float>> shapes;

  Camera<float> cam1(20.0f, img_ratio, Point3<float>(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), Point3<float>(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), Vec3<float>(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

  Sphere<float> cir1(0.2f, Point3<float>(0.2f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
  Sphere<float> cir2(7.0f, Point3<float>(0.0f, -7.0f, -1.0f));
  Sphere<float> cir3(0.5f, Point3<float>(1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
  shapes.push_back(cir1);
  //shapes.push_back(cir2);
  //shapes.push_back(cir3);

  Tracer<float> tracer(shapes);

  std::cout << "P3\n" << img_width << ' ' << img_height << "\n255" << std::endl;

  Ray<float> ray(Point3<float>(0.0f), Vec3<float>(0.0f));

  for (int j = 0; j < img_height; j++)
  {
    std::cerr << "\rScanlines remaining: " << j << ' ' << std::flush;
    for (int i = 0; i < img_width; i++){

        float x = i;
        float y = j;

        cam1.screenCords(x, y, img_width, img_height);

        ray = cam1.get_raydir(x, y);
        //ray = Ray<float>(Vec3<float>(x1, y1, 1), Point3<float>(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        tracer.iterator(ray, depth, t_Max, t_Min);
    }
  }
  std::cerr << "\n done " << std::endl;
}
```

I suspect the error is in one of these files since the spheres are actually being drawn with the colors based on normals (with the top and bottom normal colors unsurprisingly being bugged)

Here are a few examples of the output:

[image: With one sphere centered at the origin]

[image: More spheres]

Comment: Bookmarking this question to use as an example of images being used correctly. Unfortunately I'm of no help to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shall define

```
const float img_ratio = (float)img_width/img_height;
```

Which, for a 640x480 image, would be `1.333` rather than `2` as in your code.

Also in `screenCords` you subtract `1.0f` from `x` but not from `y`. It creates a tilt-shift effect.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out img_ratio! I totally forgot I previously hardcoded that. That silly overlook fixed the stretching.

Unfortunately I cannot subtract 1.0f to y (I was doing that before) without the bottom sphere "wrapping" over and appearing at the top as well. I removed it as a temporary fix, but I'm aware it's wrong. I'm not sure why it's wrapping around though.

Comment: @Tippitytopkek: It showing at the top must be because you don't check if the intersection is behind or infront of the camera. That sphere is so close to the camera that rays shooting through the upper portion of the frame intersect it behind your back.

Comment: I see, so I would have to somehow convert the intersection point back to camera coordinates and check that i's not behind behind (0, 0, -1)?

Comment: @Tippitytopkek: usually a ray-sphere intersection code already has the distance `t` of the intersection point along the ray. All you need is to tweak that code to ignore intersections with `t<0`.

Comment: I'm actually already doing that. My t_Min is 0.01 and hits are not registered if the intersection point is less than that. I also tried to make the spheres diffuse (for simple shadows) but they're exactly the same as before, if that helps in any way.

Comment: @Tippitytopkek: it must be a bug in that code then. We don't have it. It's best if you open a new question about that problem and include the relevant code there.